# Groovy list iteration and map update is only using last element in some contexts

Tags: java, groovy

Stripped down code to highlight the main components which demonstrates the behavior:

```
def template = [type: 'a', directories: [['dir': 'a/b/c']]]
def ids = [1,2,3]
def allPhases = []

ids.each { id ->
    def phase = [:]
    template.keySet().each { phase.put(it, template.get(it)) }
    phase.id = id
    phase.directories[0].put('command', "apply/${id}")
    allPhases.add(phase)
}
println(allPhases)
```

Output:

```
[
    [type:a, directories:[[dir:a/b/c, command:apply/3]], id:1],
    [type:a, directories:[[dir:a/b/c, command:apply/3]], id:2],
    [type:a, directories:[[dir:a/b/c, command:apply/3]], id:3]
]
```

I have a template and a list of values I'm iterating over. I use the template as a starting point for each value and conditionally (not shown) adding elements to keys in the map. I'm seeing that on each iteration the key `id` is being correctly set in the map but adding a key to the existing list of maps is causing an issue - it's only ever using the last value of `ids` (e.g. `3`).

Why is this happening for this some keys and not others? Does the update to the list of maps need to be done differently?

Answer (score 1):

You are writing always to the same array since your "copy" of the map
only copies the map *structure* but not its content. The *value* of
`directories` is *not copied*, it's *referenced*.

Check out one of the answers, how to do a deep copy and find a way you
like (or just solve the problem for `directories` your self.  E.g. [Deep
Copy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13155127/deep-copy-map-in-groovy)

```
import groovy.json.*

def template = JsonOutput.toJson(
        [type: 'a', directories: [['dir': 'a/b/c']]]
        )
def cloner = new JsonSlurper()

def ids = [1,2,3]
def allPhases = ids.collect { id ->
    cloner.parseText(template).tap{
            put('id', id)
            directories[0].put('command', "apply/${id}")
    }
}
println(allPhases)
```

Answer (score 0):

The following line:

```
phase.directories[0].put( 'command', "apply/${id}")
```

is overriding the value mapped to the key named `command`. So, after you have iterated over `1`, `2` and `3`, only the last value remains each time. Just to check, let us make the keys unique for each iteration by changing it to the following:

```
phase.directories[0].put( "command-${id}", "apply/${id}")
```

Then the output will be something like this:

```java
[type:a, directories:[[dir:a/b/c, command-1:apply/1, command-2:apply/2, command-3:apply/3]], id:1]
[type:a, directories:[[dir:a/b/c, command-1:apply/1, command-2:apply/2, command-3:apply/3]], id:2]
[type:a, directories:[[dir:a/b/c, command-1:apply/1, command-2:apply/2, command-3:apply/3]], id:3]
```